# Regex with characters, dots and numbers in Bash

Tags: regex, bash

I am trying to find a regex that it will check the following pattern:

`>chr28.1.1.24407.24473`

So, this pattern consists of 5 parts separated by dots. The first part is the string ">chr" following by a number (one or more digits) and all the other parts should be numbers with one or more digits.
This regex should be a part of a small script which finds first these lines and then it checks their validation.

```
HCE=$1
hceregex='^>chr[1-9]+\.[1-9]+\.[1-9]+\.[1-9]+\.[1-9]+$'
grep ">" $HCE > HCE.headers
file="HCE.headers"
lines=`cat $file`
for line in $lines
do
    if [[ ! $line =~ $hceregex ]]
    then
    echo "Invalid fasta header in HCE sequence. Check the G-Anchor   manual for the headers format"
    exit 1
    else
          echo "Brilliant!!!!"
    fi
done
```

My problem is that the regex without the escape character for the dots returns all the headers. By using the escape character it excludes everything, even the right ones.
What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Try escaping dot twice.

Comment: It doesn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, basicaly this was the problem. Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First problem is using `[1-9]` which will match only digits `1-9`. You should be using `[0-9]` to match any digit.

Second problem is use of unnecessary `cat` and unquoted variables. You should be using this code:

```
hceregex='^>chr[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$'

while read -r line; do
   if [[ ! $line =~ $hceregex ]]; then
      echo 'Invalid fasta header in HCE sequence'
   else
      echo 'Brilliant!!!!'
   fi
done < file
```

As a further optimization, you can shorten your regex to this:

```
hceregex='^>chr[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){4}$'
```

Comment: Since there are repeated parts, we can use a quantifier `hceregex='^>chr[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){4}$`

Comment: Thank you very much. Without the cat should be faster, too. This part of the code will be included in a larger one and the headers file will have thousand of headers to check.

Answer (score 1):

In your text you have zero, here `24407` but in regex not `[1-9]+`, you have to update it to:

```
^>chr[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$
```